# form_tag after success Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using form_tag

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:action=>'url'), :onclick=> "$('.submit_btn').addClass('disabled');", :complete=>$(".submit_btn").removeClass("disabled"), :method=>"post", :remote =>true do %>
...........

...............

<%= submit_tag "Create", :class=>"submit_btn", :disable_with => "Please wait..." %>
```

While form is submiting, onclick disabled the the button, which is correct. However, once I get the response it does not remove the "disabled" class from submit button. I looked online and the API docs ...but failed to find way to get this working.
 I want while form submits the data disabled the button and onresponse enable the button.

Can any one provide pointers?

Thanks
Viral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you're using jquery-ujs, there's no need to do it manually, which means that you should remove the `:onclick` and `:complete` parts - simple add `:disable_with` and jquery-ujs will do the rest for you.

So your code will become:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:action=>'url'), :method=>"post", :remote =>true do %>
<%= submit_tag "Create", :class=>"submit_btn", :disable_with => "Please wait..." %>
```

### Edit:

If you want to perform some custom operations before / during / after this AJAX request, you'd bind the form to those custom events fired by jquery-ujs ([reference here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)). For example, the following code accomplishes what you want:

```
<script>
  $('#form-id').bind({
    'ajax:before': function () {
      $('.submit_btn').addClass('disabled');
    },

    'ajax:complete': function () {
      $('.submit_btn').removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: yeah but with disable_with I cannot run disabled effect on my button...correct? It will just replace the text from "Create" to "Please Wait..". I want is to change the look of button to disable